# CLEAR 4G USB Driver for OS X 10.8

Tags: usb-modem

I just got new mac air with OSX 10.8.2. I alsoo have a 4G USB dongle. 
http://www.clear.com/support/download/usb/clear-4g-mobile-usb states at this point that they do not support 10.8, but do support 10.7.

This is a bit of offset. I know they will come out with new driver at some point, but it has been a week.

I am wondering if any one had to deal with this already, besides buying a hotspot device.

It wont let me run 10.7 driver installation on my machine...